# WPF : the SizeChanged always being fired

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

i m used ResponsiveGrid to make a Dynamic page And set a SizeChanged event in order to change  button's position . but the SizeChanged always being fired make the windows flicker ,and SizeChanged event can not stop,here is my code in .cs

```
 private void Condition_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ActualWidth > 1480)
            {
                Col1.Height = new GridLength(100.0, GridUnitType.Star);
                Col2.Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
                Row1.Width = new GridLength(5.0, GridUnitType.Star);
                Row2.Width = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);

                CommonButtonSearch.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
                CommonButtonSearch.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);

                CommonButtonSearch.Margin = new Thickness(30, (ActualHeight - 32) / 2, 0, (ActualHeight - 32) / 2);

            }
            else
            {
                Row1.Width = new GridLength(100.0, GridUnitType.Star);
                Row2.Width = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
                Col1.Height = new GridLength(5.0, GridUnitType.Star);
                Col2.Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);

                CommonButtonSearch.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
                CommonButtonSearch.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);

                CommonButtonSearch.Margin = new Thickness((ActualWidth - 120) / 2, 30, (ActualWidth - 120) / 2, 30);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is raised whenever the size is changed which may happen when you set the `Width` and `Height` properties of the rows and columns in your code.

You may want to use a variable to "suspend" events from being raised while your code is being executed:

```
private bool _handle = true;
private void Condition_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_handle)
        return;

    _handle = false;
    if (ActualWidth > 1480)
    {
        Col1.Height = new GridLength(100.0, GridUnitType.Star);
        Col2.Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
        Row1.Width = new GridLength(5.0, GridUnitType.Star);
        Row2.Width = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);

        CommonButtonSearch.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
        CommonButtonSearch.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);

        CommonButtonSearch.Margin = new Thickness(30, (ActualHeight - 32) / 2, 0, (ActualHeight - 32) / 2);

    }
    else
    {
        Row1.Width = new GridLength(100.0, GridUnitType.Star);
        Row2.Width = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
        Col1.Height = new GridLength(5.0, GridUnitType.Star);
        Col2.Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);

        CommonButtonSearch.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
        CommonButtonSearch.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);

        CommonButtonSearch.Margin = new Thickness((ActualWidth - 120) / 2, 30, (ActualWidth - 120) / 2, 30);
    }
    _handle = true;
}
```

Comment: it can not work for me the ActualWidth always change and the SizeChanged event ·is still always being fired

Comment: What does "always" mean? It fires whenever the size changes so it if fires "always", it means that the size is also changed "always".

Comment: i use  ResponsiveGrid, and set <rg:ResponsiveGrid BreakPoints="480, 960, 1480"> ,when 480 , 960, 1480 the form will change 。come to critical point like 1479 1480 1481,the change timing ,it always being fired and can not stop

Comment: If you temporarily remove the code in `Condition_SizeChanged`, does it still get invoked "always"?

Comment: it wont be invoked always。but i want to change the button position when  the sizechange, could you know other solutions?

Comment: So your code causes the event to be fired "always"? Then you haven't implemented my solution.

Comment: i implemented your solution but can not work

Comment: Are you saying that it works when you remove the code altogether but not when you return based on the value of `_handle`?

Comment: No, it's set to `false` when the event handler is invoked the first time. Look at row 4 in my code.

Comment: i means Condition_SizeChanged,  complete，  Condition_SizeChanged, still be invoke like Condition_SizeChanged ->   Condition_SizeChanged,  -> ... forever